# Is this good practice?

Tags: c#, exception

I have this extension method that allows me to retry an operation if there is an exception, a typical use is trying to write to a file, but for some reason I can't so I retry a bit later...

The extension looks like:

```
public static void WithRetry<T>(this Action action, int timeToWait = 500, int timesToRetry = 3) where T : Exception
{
    int retryCount = 0;

    bool successful = false;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            successful = true;
        }
        catch (T)
        {
            retryCount++;
            Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
            if (retryCount == timesToRetry) throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    } while (retryCount < timesToRetry && !successful);
}
```

Visual studio tells me that I'm swallowing an exception in the first catch block, is this bad?

Thanks.

Comment: Not directly related to the question: you can omit the last catch-statement as all you do is simly re-throw the exception. Related: swallowing exceptions is often a bad thing as you lose any information on an error.

Comment: What is the exact message you get from Visual Studio?

Comment: Exit point '}' swallows an exception! Consider throwing an exception instead. This is a Warning, not an Error. I do throw the exception, just not the first n times...

Comment: Do you have any code analyzers in place? I don't see any warning here.

Comment: Just the default Roslyn ExceptionAnalyzer

EA003  C# Exit point '' swallows an exception!Consider throwing an exception instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is exactly what you are trying to achieve. You are swallowing the exceptions (timesToRetry-1) times. On the last try only you are actually throwing the exception. Until then all the exceptions will be swallowed and lost. Since this is the behavior you are trying to achieve. There is no harm in suppressing the message.

But as @HimBromBeere stated remove the `catch(Exception)` block. Also you can try logging the exception on each re-try because you will loose this data. What if different kind of exception is thrown each time. There is no way to be sure.

Comment: Good tip on logging. But it being an extension method, how can I log the exception?

Comment: You need to pass the logger object as one of its parameters so that you can use it for logging.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is correct, you swallow exceptions. If you retry 10 times you will never know what went wrong the first 9 times, you only get exception number 10.

Maybe that's what you want. Personally, I would put all the occurring exceptions into an [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and throw *that* when you hit your retry count.

Maybe like this:

```
    public static void WithRetry<T>(this Action action, int timeToWait = 500, int timesToRetry = 3) where T : Exception
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        for (int tryIndex = 0; tryIndex < timesToRetry; tryIndex++)
        {
            try
            {
                action();

                return;
            }
            catch (T t)
            {
                exceptions.Add(t);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
        }

        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
```

Comment: This answer my question of how to log the intermediate exceptions with this being an extension method. Cheers